# Links not opening in current tab as well as new tab

Tags: html

I have an HTML template on which I am working and I am trying to put the target blank on the Anchor tag but the links are not opening in a new tab as well as the current tab. Please also see this [link](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/289433/NeocxFTxMN847UTMK9exeZXgFKCeQ0L6/) for refrence.

Here is my HTML section of the page:

> ```
> <div class="grid">
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="#" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>             <img  alt="Project 1" src="images/placeholders/adp8.jpg">
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a">
>                         <span class="highlight">Luds</span>
>                     </p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a">
>                         <strong>Alter Disco Podcast 8</strong>
>                     </p>
>                     <p class="text-center">
>                         <i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i>
>                     </p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/peter-clamat-alter-disco-podcast-7-superhazi-tape" class="hover-overlay">
>             <img  alt="Project 1" src="images/placeholders/500x400-0.jpg">
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Peter Clamat</span></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Süperhazi Tape</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 7</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/claudio-rotunno-alter-disco-podcast-6" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>             <img alt="Project 2" src="images/placeholders/500x400-1.jpg" />
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Cláudio Rotunno</span></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 6</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/barbara-boeing-alter-disco-podcast-5-frenetic-movements-for-unusual-people" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 3" src="images/placeholders/500x400-2.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Barbara Boeing</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Frenetic movements for unusual people</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 5</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="#!portfolio-item-4.html" class="hover-overlay">
>         <img alt="Project 4" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt004.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Phil Mill</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 4</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="#!portfolio-item-5.html" class="hover-overlay">
>         <img alt="Project 5" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt003.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">De Sena</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 3</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="#!portfolio-item-6.html" class="hover-overlay">
>         <img alt="Project 6" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt002.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Phil Mill</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 2</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="#!portfolio-item-7.html" class="hover-overlay">
>         <img alt="Project 7" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt001.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">De Sena</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 1</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: The links for project2 and 3 seem to be working fine as they are opening in new tabs. Could you explain where you are having problems?

Comment: @Ryan I am trying to open in firefox and they are not opening in current tab or new tab there is a problem with chrome as when i try open the template in chrome is shows me a blank page only with the menus

Comment: Are links to project2 and 3 working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl"` links with each respective projects link

> ```
> <div class="grid">
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>             <img  alt="Project 1" src="images/placeholders/adp8.jpg">
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a">
>                         <span class="highlight">Luds</span>
>                     </p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a">
>                         <strong>Alter Disco Podcast 8</strong>
>                     </p>
>                     <p class="text-center">
>                         <i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i>
>                     </p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/peter-clamat-alter-disco-podcast-7-superhazi-tape" class="hover-overlay"  target="_blank">
>             <img  alt="Project 1" src="images/placeholders/500x400-0.jpg">
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Peter Clamat</span></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Süperhazi Tape</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 7</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/claudio-rotunno-alter-disco-podcast-6" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>             <img alt="Project 2" src="images/placeholders/500x400-1.jpg" />
>             <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>                 <div class="hidden-xs">
>                     <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Cláudio Rotunno</span></p>
>                     <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 6</strong></p>
>                     <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://soundcloud.com/alterdisco/barbara-boeing-alter-disco-podcast-5-frenetic-movements-for-unusual-people" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 3" src="images/placeholders/500x400-2.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Barbara Boeing</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Frenetic movements for unusual people</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 5</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 4" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt004.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Phil Mill</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 4</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 5" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt003.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">De Sena</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 3</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 6" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt002.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">Phil Mill</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 2</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
>         <a href="https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl" class="hover-overlay" target="_blank">
>         <img alt="Project 7" src="images/placeholders/500x400-alt001.jpg" />
>         <div class="overlay background-90-a">
>             <div class="hidden-xs">
>                 <p class="title heading-a"><span class="highlight">De Sena</span></p>
>                 <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Alter Disco Podcast 1</strong></p>
>                 <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud heading-a"></i></p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Its still not working the links aren't opening at all i found the problem though but don't know how to resolve it. The issue is with the grid class when i remove the grid class it works fine but the layout breaks

Comment: yes the example is working but the code is not working in the template